# MySQLSyntaxErrorException when retrieving MetaData for "select ... limit ?,?" prepared query

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, metadata

I'm trying to get metadata from prepared statement after executing query with parameters in "limit" clause:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from tbl limit ?, ?");
ps.setLong(1, 0);
ps.setLong(2, 10);
ps.execute();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = ps.getMetaData();
```

code throws exception in last line:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''', ''' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1362)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.getMetaData(PreparedStatement.java:2882)
at ...... <my classes>
```

When I'm skipping retrieving ResultSetMetaData, code works just fine.
I can't find in internet and bug database any mentions for a bug.

I've tried folowing versions of connector/J: 5.1.14, 5.1.12, 5.1.9 (Maven dependency).

Server version is 5.0.77

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how prepared statement assigns parameters when you do the "setLong()".

When you use the setters in prepared statement, it encloses the parameters in single quotes .

I am not sure why the "executeQuery" works.
You will see a similar exception if you directly execute the following query.

```
"select * from tbl limit '0', '10'"
```

Instead use the following.

```
int startLimit = 0;
int endLimit = 10;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from tbl limit " + startLimit + " , " + endLimit);
ps.execute();
// you can use "Statement" if you dont have any more parameters
```

Comment: that's it, to workaround this issue I had to remove RSMD and just use ResultSet.getXXX(columnTitle) methods.

So, the bug is either in Connector/J or in the way how MySQL handles limit clause?

Comment: @Askar Kalykov yes I agree, looks like a bug to me.